# Step in RISC-V program on a Pipelined Processor

Tags: cpu, cpu-pipelines, risc-v

I struggle to understand a step in the following solution to a RISC-V exercise.

---

**Exercise:** a pipelined RISC-V processor with no data forwarding paths executes the following program. For each instruction and clock cycle, determine the stage of the processor involved.

**Solution:**

[image]

**What I expected:**

[image]

---

What I fail to grasp is how the instruction `sw x3, 16(x8)` can be decoded (ID) *before* the write-back (WB) of instruction `add x3,x2,x1`.

My understanding was that we begin the ID step with the instruction containing the register names (e.g. `x3`, `x2`, `x1`) and end with the *data* of the source registers already read and ready to be given (in the next step: EX) to the ALU.

As an example, if register `x3` contains `0xFF` *after* instruction `add x3, x2, x1` has been ran, then I'd imagine that by the end of the ID step of instruction `sw x3, 16(x8)` the 'Read data 1' signal (see picture below) would have a value of `0xFF`. For that to be the case the value of `x3` must have been updated i.e. the WB stage of `add x3, x2, x1` must have been run first. Why is my reasoning wrong?

[image]

Comment: Why would you not be able to decode it? Decoding an instruction is not executing it. Decoding it means figuring out what the instruction does. Clearly the processor needs to figure out what the instruction does before it does it.